# Counting number of document in which each term appears

Tags: python, pandas, binary-search-tree, tf-idf

I have a list of document of 5 documents stored at each node in a tree. In each list there are a number of words apprearing which might repeat several times in same document as well as other documents. I want to take a count of number of documents where each word is apprearing.
For example: A is parent node and B,C are child nodes. A,B,C has 5 documents.

```
A=[['a','b'],['a','a'],['c','d'],['a','c'],['d','e']]
```

I want result in the form of `{'a':3,'b':1,'c':2,'d':2,'e':1}`

Below is the code I am using but it is not taking count of each document but it is taking count of number of times each word is appearing in the document.

```
def get_count(node):
    word_count_dict = defaultdict(int)
    next_node=[]
    for i in range(len(node.documents)):
        for words in node.documents[i]:
            word_count_dict[words] +=1
        node.word_count = word_count_dict
    for child in node.children:
        next_node.append(child)
    if next_node:
        for nn in next_node:
            get_count(nn)
    return word_count_dict

get_count(A)
```

Kindly help how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call the `get_count` on the children, but don't assign the result or do anything with it

From what I understand you want, `set` and `Counter` are what you really need.

Assuming `node.documents` and `node.children` are iterable (which they should be) this can work

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

def get_count(node):

    words_per_document = map(set, node.documents)
    word_count = Counter(chain.from_iterable(words_per_document))
    for child in node.children:
        word_count += get_count(child)

    return word_count
```

I see little reason to set-up a queue

Answer (score 1):

With in-built packages. But there should be a simple way.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
dict(Counter(chain.from_iterable(set(l) for l in A)))
#{'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 1}
```